# Angular handle events in own Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, electron

I'm working on an Electron App written with AngularJS. In the Main Process of the Electron app, i'm listening for the DownloadItem events. So, every time a user downloads a file, the event gets triggered. In my Main.js, i have the following code.

```
  win.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
    item.once('done', (event, state) => {
    if (state === 'completed') {
      win.webContents.send('download-message', 'completed', item.getSavePath());
    } else if (state === 'interrupted') {
      win.webContents.send('download-message', 'failed');
    }
  })
});
```

On the Angular Side of things, i'm waiting for such an event in the "main" Controller (which represents the Starting point of the App). So, here I have some Code that looks like this:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.on('download-message', function (event, method, filepath) {
    if (method === 'completed') {
    // Do something interesting
  } else if (method === 'failed') {
    // Do something interesting
  }
});
```

This works just fine, but it feels kind of ugly to handle all of these event in the main Application Controller. I would like to separate it to its own Controller (e.g downloadController).

I thought about it to listen for this events in its own Service (e.g downloadsService), but since i want to manipulate the view (e.g show some success/failure message) of the App, i don't think this would be the right place for this functionality.

So, i'm looking for a good way to separate this functionality to a specific Controller.

Maybe I just do not really understand the concepts of Angular and its Controllers, so any advice would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the events in whichever controller(s) are used to modify your view. You just have to ensure that the controller handling the event shares $scope with the controller triggering the event.

When you trigger an Angular event, you can either use $emit or $broadcast. Calling

```
$scope.$emit(name, args);
```

will send the event upwards in the scope hierarchy, so if you have a parent controller, it will hear about the event. $broadcast sends the event downwards. However, if your controllers are all registered at the same hierarchical level, you have to use $rootScope.

Whether you use $rootScope or $scope, make sure you inject it into the controller that is listening for the event as well as the controller triggering the event.